# Boost websocket server c++, как отключить неактивных клиентов

Tags: c++, websocket, boost, boost.asio

Использую код из примера синхронного веб-сокет сервера библиотеки Boost https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/sync/websocket_server_sync.cpp

Код не прикрпляю, потому что не знаю вообще как поступать

Вопрос:
А что, если ко мне подключится много ботов и будут просто висеть на сервере? read -- блокируется, пока не получит сообщения.

Я пытался решить проблему так:
заносил указатели на подключенные вебсокеты в map с меткой по времени. Из отдельного потока пробегался по этому массиву и закрывал "неактивные" соединения, но заблокированный read в потоке чтения вместо исключения кидает assert.

Есть ли какой-то способ сделать тайм-аут по ожиданию сообщения от клиента? И вообще как в таких ситуациях поступают?

Comment: В случае tcp сокетов asio (beast вроде бы работает аналогично) это делается так: все операции чтения осуществляются асинхронно, на каждую операцию чтения создается deadline_timer с некоторым заданным временем ожидания. Обработчик таймера вызывает `socket.cancel()`, обработчик асинхронного чтения в случае успеха вызывает `deadline_timer.cancel()`, в случае неудачи - по коду ошибки понимает, что это был `socket.cancel()`, и дальше разрывает соединение (`shutdown`), или реализует другую логику. Чтобы не запутаться в асинхронных операциях, можно использовать `asio::spawn` либо `boost::fiber`.